# Replacing Akka Schedulers with plain java

Tags: java, executorservice

I want to get rid of Akka Scheduler. Could someone please let me know the best way to implement the following in plain java using Executor ?

```
 operation = Akka.system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(
            Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
            this,
            Akka.system().dispatcher());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this

```
    ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    ex.schedule(this, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: looks promising... will try this